# getting permalinks from wordpress in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm an old hand at PHP but have only dabbled in wordpress so excuse my ignorance:

I'm trying to get a list of pages by their relative permalinks for example:

"/home",
"/contact"

I can't see which function would be good for this and want to avoid getting hacky.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages and then http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_link in a loop. I don't know if there's a "better" way, but this will work for sure.

```
$pages = get_pages(); 
  foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $permalink = get_page_link( $page->ID );
  }
```

For local/relative URLs you can use: `get_page_uri($page->ID)`

Comment: yeah i get a slashed string with the full remote url.. I guess I can str_replace but not sure how messy that will get do you know if there's a relative version of get_page_link?

Comment: you can try get_permalink($page->ID), but I guess it would give back te same